# How do I add a class of current to my navigational list items and links?

Tags: php, navigation

I've tried a few different ways to add a class of current on my navigation.

I read an article on doing so at: http://alistapart.com/article/keepingcurrent

So far I'm having no luck incorporating any of the ways into my site.

I feel like I'm missing something.

I pull my navigation into the site with an includes file called nav.php:

```
    <div id="nav">
    <div id="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav-content" class="top menu">
            <li<?php if ($thisPage=="home") 
            echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>>
            <a href="/index2013.php">Home</a></li>

            <li<?php if ($thisPage=="portfolio") 
            echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>>
            <a href="/design/designsystems/unitedway/unitedway.php">Portfolio</a></li>

            <li<?php if ($thisPage=="services") 
            echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>>
            <a href="/services/services.php">Services</a></li>

            <li<?php if ($thisPage=="resources") 
            echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>>
            <a href="/resources/resources.php">Resources</a></li>

            <li<?php if ($thisPage=="blog") 
            echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>>
            <a href="http://kristinemorical.com/wordpress/kristine-blog/">Blog</a></li>

            <li<?php if ($thisPage=="contact") 
            echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>>
            <a href="/contactinfo/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I have in the body of the index page:

```
<?php $thisPage="home"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Kristine Morical : Home</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="Kristine Morical" />
<?php include('http://www.kristinemorical.com/includes/head.php'); ?>
</head>

    <body id="body">

        <?php include('http://www.kristinemorical.com/includes/header.php'); ?>

        <?php include('http://www.kristinemorical.com/includes/nav.php'); ?>

        <div id="outer" class="clearfix">

        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <?php //include('http://www.kristinemorical.com/includes/sidebar.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="content" role="main">      

        </div> <!-- end #main -->

        </div> <!-- end #outer -->

        <?php include('http://www.kristinemorical.com/includes/footer.php'); ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) condition for cleaner code, and second, use a css `class` for easier styling (which would allow multiple, if you add other navigation elements):

```
<li<?= ($thisPage=="services" ? ' class="currentPage"' : '') ?>>
    <a href="/services/services.php">Services</a>
</li>
```

It can get tedious too to always set `$thisPage`, so you could go step further and have PHP try to figure it out based on the current request uri.

If you have problems where the class is never printing when it should, then do a `var_dump` or something on `$thisPage` to make sure it's being set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav-content" class="top menu">
            <?php if ($thisPage=="home")  echo "<li id=\"currentpage\">"; else echo "<li>";?>
            <a href="/index2013.php">Home</a></li>

            <?php if ($thisPage=="portfolio")  echo "<li id=\"currentpage\">"; else echo "<li>";?>
            <a href="/design/designsystems/unitedway/unitedway.php">Portfolio</a></li>

            <?php if ($thisPage=="services")  echo "<li id=\"currentpage\">"; else echo "<li>";?>
           <a href="/services/services.php">Services</a></li>

            <?php if ($thisPage=="resources")  echo "<li id=\"currentpage\">"; else echo "<li>";?>
            <a href="/resources/resources.php">Resources</a></li>

            <?php if ($thisPage=="blog")  echo "<li id=\"currentpage\">"; else echo "<li>";?>
            <a href="http://kristinemorical.com/wordpress/kristine-blog/">Blog</a></li>

            <?php if ($thisPage=="contact")  echo "<li id=\"currentpage\">"; else echo "<li>";?>
           <a href="/contactinfo/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will work if you're using ID tags but if you really want to use a class, then you should be using class tags instead.  It depends on how you're declaring the class in your head tags of your webpage or in your css file. If you're declaring the class with the # sign then the above code will work but it's not the best practice. You would want to declare the class with a period sign instead and then use class tags in your webpage.